# Convert JSON string to List<class>

Tags: c#, json, list, object, casting

I am trying to convert Json string to `List<MyClass>`

Unable to cast object of type `'System.Object[]'` to type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'`

```
private class ContractList
{
   public string prop1;
   public string prop2;
   public string prop3;
}
object[] objList = (object[]) serializer.DeserializeObject(JsonString);
IEnumerable<MyClass> objList = (IEnumerable<MyClass>) objList;
foreach(MyClass obj in objList )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: rather `serializer.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(...)`if it's an array

Comment: You new to use NewtonSoft.json package and then use command like JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<MyClass>(JsonString).

Answer (score 0):

Solve my problem with below code.

```
MyClass[] SourceData = serializer.Deserialize<MyClass[]>(responseData);
foreach(MyClass obj in SourceData)
{

}
```